# JSON send as kafka producer message and consuming by spark structured streaming -parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, jsonnode

I would like to know how to send a JSON string as message to kafka topic using scala function and Consumed by the using readstream() in spark structured streaming, save as parquet format.
Currently using following code, but the parquet file not getting created. Please help to get the parquet file with data. This also implemented as functions and required to call those 2 functions in integration-tests.

JSON message sent to Kafka topic-

```
object kafkaProducer extends App {

    def sendMessages(): Unit = {

        //define topic
        val topic = "spark-topic"

        //define producer properties
        val props = new java.util.Properties()
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        props.put("client.id", "KafkaProducer")
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer")

        //create producer instance
        val kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer[String, JsonNode](props)

        //create object mapper
        val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
        mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

        //mapper Json object to string
        def toJson(value: Any): String = {
            mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
        }

        //send producer message
        val jsonstring =
        s"""{
            | "id": "0001",
            | "name": "Peter"
            |}
         """.stripMargin

        val jsonNode: JsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonstring)
        val rec = new ProducerRecord[String, JsonNode](topic, jsonNode)
        kafkaProducer.send(rec)
        //println(rec)    
    }
}
```

---

Spark Structured Streaming - kafka consumer

```
object sparkConsumer extends App {

    def receiveMessages(): Unit = {

    //create a SparkSession for consumer
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("SparkStructConsumer")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    //Subscribe the stream from Kafka
    val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "spark-topic")
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("groupid","kafka-spark-group")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .load


    //create schema for json string
    val data_Schema: StructType = new StructType()
      .add("id", StringType)
      .add("name", StringType)

    //Convert Stream according to schema along with TimeStamp
    val df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)").as[(String, Timestamp)]
      .select(from_json($"value", data_Schema).as("data"), $"timestamp")
      .select("data.id", "data.name", "timestamp")
      .toDF("Id", "Name", "Timestamp")


    //writing as parquet
    val query = df1
      .writeStream
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
      .queryName("table")
      .format("parquet")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/Users/s/desktop/SparkOutput")
      .option("path", "/Users/s/desktop/SparkOutput")
      .start()

      query.awaitTermination()

    }
}
```

---

Integration Tests

```
class SparkKafkaIntegrationTests extends FlatSpecLike with Matchers with EmbeddedKafka {

    import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

    "Kafka producer sent JSON message" should "Consumed by the Spark Structured Streaming consumer" in {

        //define zookeeper and kafkaserver
        val userDefinedConfig = EmbeddedKafkaConfig(kafkaPort = 9092, zooKeeperPort = 2181)

        val properties = new Properties()
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")


        kafkaProducer.sendMessages()

        sparkConsumer.receiveMessages()

    }
}
```

Thank you.
Shaamil.

Comment: By the way, Kafka Connect is an open source framework and Confluent provides an plugin for taking JSON (or Avro) data from Kafka and writing as Parquet (using Hadoop libraries). I would argue that's better than writing all this code yourself with little error handling.

Comment: In any case, you can use `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer`... There is no real reason to have a JsonNode object here except as a deserializer in a consumer

Comment: okay, thank you.. sounds well.. can you please share me links or sample code or repos for the same kind of..

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs#kafka-connect-hdfs-connector  and http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect

Comment: Thanks, assume Kafka connect can be used for continues streams as well

Comment: That's what it's primarily meant for, yes